# Changing value of Rational Resampler block in real time

Tags: filter, gnuradio, resample

I wanted to change Decimation value of Rational Resampler Block in real time. Tried to use QT GUI Range Block, but failed. It's possible with Range Block? Maybe somebody know how to resolve changing Decimation value in real time using another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [keep 1 in N block](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Keep_1_in_N). N will act as decimation rate that you can change through QT GUI.

Take into consideration that [not all block parameters can be changed in runtime](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Guided_Tutorial_GRC#Variable_Controls).